# Show out of stock product "variants" for configurable products

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, configurable-product

do you know how to show the product "variants" (sorry if this terminology is incorrect) even if it is out of stock and possibly show "Out of stock" instead of the price?

So for example I have a T-shirt configurable product, so I have added a green single product and an orange single product as Associated products. The orange product is out of stock, I still want it to be displayed in the dropdown menu so customers know that there's an orange option but it should be out of stock so the customer can't order.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view out of stock variable in product by  remove this code

`if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {` from function `getAllowProducts()` at class    `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`.

So you need to `rewrite`  class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`

**Step1:** You   will need to create `/app/code/local/Amit/MyProduct/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/` and file `Configurable.php`

**and code:**

```
<?php
class Amit_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable{

 public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $products = array();
            $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                }
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }

}
```

**Step2:** create  config.xml `/app/code/local/Amit/MyProduct/etc/` and code  is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Amit_MyProduct>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Amit_MyProduct>
 </modules>
 <global>
   <blocks>
    <catalog>
         <rewrite>
              <product_view_type_configurable>Amit_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
             </rewrite>
      </catalog>
  </blocks>
 </global>
</config>
```

**Step3:** Create `Amit_MyProduct.xml` at a`pp/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Amit_MyProduct>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <active>active</active>
    </Amit_MyProduct>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you Amit. I will create a full backup of the site overnight and try that tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hi Amit Bera,
I have just done the fix that you said and it's pulling through the product and if added to basket it shows the popup with "This product is currently out of stock.<br/>" message which is great too, however I was wondering - is it possible to add "(out of stock)" to the end of the product variant in the dropdown menu so the customer knows in advance that it isn't in stock?

Comment: Magento is provide to backorders  facility which give this type solution ,where customer can place out of stock products http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-products

Comment: http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/configuring-inventory-information/

Comment: But disabled products are also showing in dropdown after implementing this? why???

Comment: put a condition $product->getStatus()==1 in for loop

Comment: @AmitBera, do we have same for m2 also? I need to implement same in magento2 also

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any rewrites.
Just use the event `catalog_controller_product_init`.
So add this to the config.xml from one of your modules inside the `<frontend><events>` tag

```
<catalog_controller_product_init>
    <observers>
        <[module]>
            <class>[module]/observer</class>
            <method>showOutOfStock</method>
        </[module]>
    </observers>
</catalog_controller_product_init>
```

Then create the file `Observer.php` inside the `Model` folder with this content

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function showOutOfStock($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
            Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we do the same in m2 also?

Comment: most likely. I just don't know how. Maybe look for the method `getSkipSaleableCheck`, not sure in what class it is. And make an `after` plugin for it, that returns true.

Comment: I am looking for it, but nowhere finding the proper solution