# Get Stock Level for Configurable Product Attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I have a bit of code that overwrites some basic functionality and shows out-of-stock products in the dropdown for configurable products (taken from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42706/show-out-of-stock-product-variants-for-configurable-products)).

That all works fine, but instead of them adding to card and *then* just getting a notification to say it's out of stock, I'd like to append (Out of Stock) after the option title.

These are the relevant lines from the template file (configurable.phtml):

```
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <?php #Mage::log('<pre>'. print_r($_attribute->isAvailable(), 1) .'</pre>', null, 'mum.log', true); ?>
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" 
                    id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" 
                    class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It's more or less the base theme template file with the addition of the `Mage::log()`.

I've tried using:

- `$_attribute->isAvailable()`
- `$_attribute->isSaleable()`

But both don't work, which led me to use `get_class_methods()` on `$_attribute` and I can see I only get:

```
(
    [0] => addPrice
    [1] => getLabel
    [2] => getIdFieldName
    [3] => getId
    [4] => setId
    [5] => getResourceName
    [6] => getResourceCollection
    [7] => getCollection
    [8] => load
    [9] => afterLoad
    [10] => save
    [11] => afterCommitCallback
    [12] => isObjectNew
    [13] => getCacheTags
    [14] => getCacheIdTags
    [15] => cleanModelCache
    [16] => delete
    [17] => getResource
    [18] => getEntityId
    [19] => clearInstance
    [20] => __construct
    [21] => _addFullNames
    [22] => _initOldFieldsMap
    [23] => _prepareSyncFieldsMap
    [24] => isDeleted
    [25] => hasDataChanges
    [26] => setIdFieldName
    [27] => addData
    [28] => setData
    [29] => unsetData
    [30] => unsetOldData
    [31] => getData
    [32] => _getData
    [33] => setDataUsingMethod
    [34] => getDataUsingMethod
    [35] => getDataSetDefault
    [36] => hasData
    [37] => __toArray
    [38] => toArray
    [39] => _prepareArray
    [40] => __toXml
    [41] => toXml
    [42] => __toJson
    [43] => toJson
    [44] => toString
    [45] => __call
    [46] => __get
    [47] => __set
    [48] => isEmpty
    [49] => _underscore
    [50] => _camelize
    [51] => serialize
    [52] => getOrigData
    [53] => setOrigData
    [54] => dataHasChangedFor
    [55] => setDataChanges
    [56] => debug
    [57] => offsetSet
    [58] => offsetExists
    [59] => offsetUnset
    [60] => offsetGet
    [61] => isDirty
    [62] => flagDirty
)
```

So it seems, there's no obvious method for handling my task.

I then moved onto `getData()` as that seemed the most likely avenue.

But using `array_keys()` shows:

```
(
    [0] => product_super_attribute_id
    [1] => product_id
    [2] => attribute_id
    [3] => position
    [4] => product_attribute
    [5] => label
    [6] => use_default
    [7] => prices
    [8] => decorated_is_even
    [9] => decorated_is_last
)
```

I also tried setting it in the Configurable.php file (mentioned above):

```
if ($product->isAvailable() != 1) {
    $product->setData('name', $product->getData('name'). ' (Out of Stock)');
}

$products[] = $product;
```

But that does it to the product title, **not** the option in the dropdown menu.

How do I go about appending "Out of Order" to configurable product options if they're... well out of stock?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$stockData = [];
$typeInstance = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance();
$configurableAttributes = $typeInstance->getConfigurableAttributes($configurableProduct);
foreach ($configAttributes as $attribute) {
    $simpleProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($attribute->getProductId());
    $stockData[$attribute->getProductId()]['is_saleable'] = $simpleProduct->isSaleable();
}
```

For Magento 1 replace `$this->productRepository->getById($attribute->getProductId())` with `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($attribute->getProductId())`.

Comment: can you write this as a Magento 1 answer please :) $configurableProduct isn't a variable in my code :S

Comment: I don't know which template you're modifying, but try `$_product`, if you don't have it load product like this: `$_product = $this->getProduct()`. I would also recommend to create a helper or block method, put this code there and pass product to the new method to build the `$stockData` array there, but not in a template.